# Find in which panelarray a panel is located

Tags: c#, arrays, panel

I'm working on a school assignment where we have to use (a) custom class(es) to make a working game of snake in which you need multiple snakes.

Im trying to make these snakes using panel arrays.
1 panel array named Snk and 1 named AI(the AI is something if haven't started with).
These are made like this:(this works)

```
//stated in public partial class Form1 : Form
        readonly PnlSnk[] Snk = new PnlSnk[200];
        readonly PnlSnk[] AI = new PnlSnk[200];
   
//Stated in public Form1()
            Snk[1] = new PnlSnk()
            {
                Size = new Size(16, 16),
                Location = new Point(ClientSize.Width / 3, ClientSize.Height / 2),
                BackColor = Color.Red,
                Name = "Snk-1"
            };
            Snk[1].Length++;
            AI[1] = new PnlSnk()
            {
                Size = new Size(16, 16),
                Location = new Point(ClientSize.Width / 3 * 2, ClientSize.Height / 2),
                BackColor = Color.Blue,
                Name = "AI-1"
            };
            AI[1].Length++;
            Controls.Add(Snk[1]);
            Controls.Add(AI[1]);
```

the code to the custom panels:

```
class PnlSnk : Panel
    {
        internal string Direction = "D";
        internal int Length = 1;
    }
```

and i have this grow function(this doesnt work):

```
private void Grow(PnlSnk P)
        {
            // this is the difficult part
            PnlSnk[] S = null;
            foreach (PnlSnk[] PS in Controls)
            {
                if (PS.contains) S = PS;
            }
            // end of difficult part
            S[S[1].Length] = new PnlSnk()
            {
                Size = new Size(16, 16),
                Location = S[S.Length - 1].Location,
                BackColor = S[1].BackColor
            };
            Controls.Add(S[S[1].Length]);
            S[1].Length++;
        }
```

I know im only adding Snk[1] and not the whole Snk array to the controls, but this kinda visualizes what im trying to do.
Im trying to make it so when grow gets triggered it will find out to which array the panel, which will either be Snk[1] or AI[1](because those are the heads), belongs in and grow only that array.
The AI snake is eventually going to be toggle-able so it wont always be there.
So how can my Grow function know which array it needs to grow?

Comment: "So how can my Grow function know which array it needs to grow?"  Your `Grow(PnlSnk P)` method receives a "PnlSnk".  How is it getting that reference?  Is the user clicking on the Panel?  Hitting keys on the keyboard?  Does your game have a notion of an "active" snake vs. a "non-active" snake?

Comment: If you only have a reference to a PnlSnk, and want to know what array it belongs to, then you can't have all of you arrays hard-coded separately like that.  What you need is an ARRAY of ARRAYS so you can iterate over ALL the snakes and see if the PnlSnk is contained within.  You could also use a `List<PnlSnk[]>` to hold all the snakes.